# Firebase transaction weird behaviour

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm setting up a **chat API**, in order to get my client write on my **RealTime Database** to do that I use some **transaction** and all of them are working just fine but one any help would be much appreciated

*I work using the firebase cloud functions emulator so I print alot to debug don't mind that*

```
  update (req, res, next) {
      admin.database().ref().child("post").child(req.body.id).transaction(post => {
          console.log("THIS LOG GETS PRINTED");
          if (post) {
              console.log("THIS LOG DOESN'T");
              var timestamp = + new Date();
              if (res.locals.uid === post.author) {
                  var message = {text: req.body.message, timestamp: Math.round(timestamp / 1000), isAdmin: false};
                  post.message.push(message)
              }
              return post
          }
      }).then(result => {
          res.status(200).send(result);
      }).catch(error => {
          res.status(500).send(error);
      })
  }
```

**Ouput :**

```
THIS LOG GETS PRINTED
```

Comment: I think this could be expected behaviour - the function may be called multiple times - and post may be null (if the document does not exist)

Comment: Putting ```return post``` outside of the *if (post) statement* did the job thanks for the hint

Comment: @Falco Thanks for helping a fellow developer. Feel like writing it up in an answer, so that Francky can accept it?